# Burger menu not going to correct position

Tags: html, css

I have made a burger menu for my site but the dropdown menu/ element does not go inside the menu icon. It moves the wrong way. It goes from left to right but I need it to go from right to left. I can't figure out how to make the menu move the other way. I have tried to tweak some of the tags but either it's not worked or it's broken.

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2%;
  left: 93%;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#menuToggle a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About us</li></a>
      <a href="rule_and_policies.html"><li>Rules</li></a>
      <a href="support_us.html"><li>Support us</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: add some html so we can see how it look.

Comment: Sorry here you go

Comment: Hi, if you can create a short demo on jsfiddle and share the link, we might help you better.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=2d2ISrAub2 just be sure to make the result as big as possible to see the problem. and ignore the rest of the website like name brand etc.